# Can I run rails server with https://localhsot:1025 on my development machine Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-14.04

I want to run my rails project local server with https request because I need to integrate the third party which allows https only. I need to integrate it with my local machine to develop and test few features. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to tunnel SSL connections to your dev machine. There are other options out there as well.

Comment: I got the setup and it works for me. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1daMCJeh5yM